# Cluster utilization graph on Grafana and PromQL

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm trying to build a graph like this into a dashboard:
[image: Utilization graph]
The goal is to be able to tell at a glance if a cluster is over utilized or weirdly unbalanced in workload (typically I don't want the stack to reach over 80%, or queuing starts to happen).

I'm using the following query:

```
max by (nodeName) (max_over_time(some_executor_utilization{nodeName=~"someCustomer-.*"}[5m])) 
* 
(100.0 / 9)
```

Note the adjustment at the end, the metric returns a value in the `[0-1]` interval, to get to a percent value, I need to adjust by the number of nodes.

A 100% graph doesn't work (it makes it harder to tell if you're in a good place or not).

The question is, **how can I compute the number of nodes in the query itself?**

Instead of having to know it beforehand. It should be possible to tell with just the label matching expression `nodeName=~"someCustomer-.*"`, but any query that counts it, doesn't have the proper labels so the arithmetic doesn't seem to work.

For example this obtains the number of nodes:

```
count(count by (nodeName) (count_over_time(some_executor_utilization{nodeName=~"someCustomer-.*"}[$__range])))
```

(it yields 9 in the example data).

But I cannot use to divide compute the scaling factor, the labels don't match.

Looking for workarounds, if I create a dashboard, I can define a template variable as follows:

```
query_result(count(count by (nodeName) (count_over_time(some_executor_utilization{nodeName=~"someCustomer-.*"}[$__range]))))
```

But this yields something like:

```
{} 9 1702826153000
```

Rather than just `9` for some reason and I just want to extract the 9.

Ideally I would like to avoid the templating dependency (i.e. compute straight in the query), but if that's not possible at least use that.

Comment: I fail to understand your question. Are you looking for a way to calculate what currently is a constant 9 in you query? If so, what 9 actually represents? Is it number of distinct nodeNames?

Comment: It's the number of nodes in this case, which is roughly the number of distinct "nodeName" values in the graph.

I cannot divide by:

count(max_over_time(some_executor_utilization{nodeName=~"someCustomer-.*"}[$__range])) 

Because the labels do not match. 

I would need to to disaggregate the series and add a label per node for it to work.

Comment: I can say fully understand your situation or problem still, but it feels like you can use something like `<your_current_query> / scalar(count(count by (nodeName) (some_executor_utilization{nodeName=~"someCustomer-.*"})))`. Here I convert divisor to a number (instead of time series), thus no need for label matching. Alternatively, you can use [vector matching](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching) in situations of mismatch in labels.